# EC2 instance elastic ip association in case of several network interfaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance with two network interfaces, one with a DeviceIndex 0 and one with a DeviceIndex 1. The both have the same security group.

I can associate an Elastic IP to the both interfaces but using ssh, i can connect to the one of DeviceIndex 0 only.

I looked to AWS documentation, but i did not find anything about that, instead reading the documentation it seems that i should be able to connect to the two interfaces.

Could someone explain why I can connect to DeviceId 0 interface only?

Regards

I try to associate two network interfaces to an insance and to connect to the both interfaces thru ssh.

Comment: You need to add [multiple ListenAddress lines to ssh_config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28934068/multiple-public-ip-addresses-on-aws-ec2-vpc)

Comment: Thanks for the comment @AnonCoward . I am not so sure The sshd config file does not define ListenAddress so it should listen on all adresses if i understood corectly (see https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1296112 ) .